# socket.io inside of loop doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to emit events inside of loop. But, just launch the first event(start) and once.

The behavior in console must be:
a
emit event start
emit event finish
b
emit event start
emit event finish

another again

a
emit event start
emit event finish
b
emit event start
emit event finish

However, it's behave the next way:

a
emit event start
b

another again

a
b

Why the event only is emit once?

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var sleep = require('sleep');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
});

server.listen(3000);




function B() {

    this.bundles = ['a', 'b'];
    this.currentPosition = 0;

    this.run = function() {
        var bundle = this.bundles[this.currentPosition];

        console.log(bundle);


        io.emit('start', { 'bundle': bundle });
        io.emit('finish', { 'bundle': bundle });

        ++this.currentPosition;
        if (this.bundles[this.currentPosition] === undefined) {
            this.currentPosition = 0;
        }

        sleep.sleep(2);
        this.run();
    }
}


//wait to start server
setTimeout(function(){ 
    var b = new B();
b.run();
 }, 6000);
```

Comment: I don't see where you handle the emitted messages!

Comment: You're calling a function recursively with no termination condition. This is going to blow up when you run out of stack. Why not `setInterval`?

Comment: "Why not setInterval?" Usually it's because they aren't aware of a better solution. Hence the reason they asked the question. Why not an answer? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing it to a `setInterval`.

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/zGdQXQ

```
    this.run = function() {
        var bundle = this.bundles[this.currentPosition];

        console.log(bundle);


        io.emit('start', { 'bundle': bundle });
        io.emit('finish', { 'bundle': bundle });

        ++this.currentPosition;
        if (this.bundles[this.currentPosition] === undefined) {
            this.currentPosition = 0;
        }
    }
    setInterval(this.run.bind(this), 2000);
```

The interval will run every 2 seconds and won't flood your call stack.

Whenever you call a function from another function, you build a call stack.

```
function foo() {
  bar();
}
function bar() {
  console.log('end of stack, returning');
}
foo();
```

The above code would build a stack like this:

```
-> event loop
  -> foo
    -> bar
      -> console.log
```

Then as the functions start returning, they pop off the stack one by one. What this means is that when you call a function from within itself, you will definitely exhaust the call stack if the recursive calls never stop.

```
function foo() {
  foo();
}
foo();
```

This would result in an ugly call stack that will run your memory dry.

```
-> event loop
  -> foo
    -> foo
      -> foo
        -> foo
          -> foo
            -> etc...
```

[image]

You can see that the JavaScript engine even tries to detect when this is happening and throw an exception. The engine doesn't always catch these though if the recursive stack is more complicated. It's best to just avoid it and stick to `setInterval`.

By using `setInterval` you're registering a function with node and telling it to fire it each time a certain number of milliseconds has passed. This saves your call stack because the function is fired, returns, and then starts again when the node event loop detects that `n` milliseconds has passed again. No infinite call stack that would result in a...

[image]

...Stack Overflow [image]

PS - Now you understand this site's own logo. It's a call stack :)

Comment: It's working! but I don't understand the difference between use recursive function and use setInterval. Could you explain me?

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? I explained how a call stack works and why it would crash the way you were doing it.

Comment: I understand everything better. Thanks very much

Comment: How can I clear the interval? When the for loop is done, I want it to end and continue with the rest of the code in the function

Comment: @Wexoni `setInterval` returns an ID number. Just assign that number to a variable and pass it to `clearInterval` when you want to terminate it. `var intervalId = setInterval(this.run.bind(this), 2000);` and then `clearInterval(intervalId);`.